# How to get a value on my jsf page using another value in my backing bean

Tags: hibernate, jsf

i have a jsf page on which I have some values to display for e.g. box_name,appl_server_name which are not present in my backing bean.But I have values like box_id,appl_server_id which are also present in the backing bean where box_name and appl_server_name are present respectively.How can i display box_name and appl_server_name using box_id and appl_server_id.

Comment: The question is not quite clear. Please add some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a value to an UIInput like "box_id.setSubmittedValue(yourValue);" in your backing bean.

Comment: but I want the value from my database and that could be retrived only by using the getter setter...any inputs on that??

Comment: Can you please give an example, how do you realised it now?

Comment: I want box_name value(which is a column in box_master table where box_id is my primary key) and i have with me box_id value only in my present backing bean...how do I use box_id now to get box_name

Comment: Mmhh...i think, there are more solutions. (1) you can select box_id and box_name from your database table and store it in an String[] or List<String, String> (2) you can use the box_id and do a second query with box_name to select and the box_id in your where clause

Comment: Ur both the options are good but i have to get more than two values in the similar fashion on my JSF page so i feel that these options are not feasible

Comment: Okay, then make a new Class, in which you can store the values u need. Then you can fill the values in this Class from your query and use it from your backing bean on your jsp site by using it like this: #{myBean.myClass.box_name}

Comment: I used this way and it worked for me fine... hope that works for you too!